# When I send DELETE request to the server I get `Forbidden 403 error` from server

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.7 to build `REST API`. Everything is going fine on my local server. But after deploying my application on the live server its give an error on `DELETE` request. Even I used

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
      Allow from all
</Limit>
```

this code snippet end of the`.htaccess`.

Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: What Apache version? That looks like 2.2 syntax... it would be `Require all granted` in 2.4

Comment: Yes, Apache 2.2

Comment: What kind of "error" is given? Is there anything written to the server's error log?

Comment: **Forbidden**
You don't have permission to access /laravel/mx_shop_store_and_owner/public/api/fees/16 on this server.

Comment: Sorry, Server apache version is 2.4

Comment: How to do this `Require all granted` in Apache 2.4?